# Returning stringbuilder object

Tags: java

What should be returned in this code? I am just working with `StringBuilder`s and I don't know how I can return `StringBuilder` objects.

```
public String toProtocolString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(Integer.toString(points.length)).append(' ');
    sb.append(Integer.toString(points[0].length)).append(' ');
    for (int[] x : points)
        for (int y : x)
            sb.append(Integer.toString(y)).append(' ');
    //remove extra space at end
    sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length()-1);
    return ??????;
```

Comment: Do some search please

Comment: `sb.append(Integer.toString`, really? see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append-int- You should also consider using braces for if/for etc and use them always

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To return a `StringBuilder` object you need to change the return type of your function signature from `String` to `StringBuilder`. But in most of the cases you don't want to do that because you will need another instance of `StringBuilder` in the callee method. So an elegant solution is that you return a variable of type `String`

In order to return a variable of type string just do this

`return sb.toString();`

Answer (score 1):

If you need to return a `String`, as the signature of your method suggests, you should

```
return sb.toString();
```

Otherwise, change the return type to `StringBuilder` and

```
return sb;
```

Answer (score 0):

Return string value of stringbuilder using toString() method. More about it is in [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)

```
return sb.toString();
```